# Cannot connect to the database when using Yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2

I am getting this error when I am using Yii2

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Here is my code in db.php:

```
<?php
   return [
      'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
      'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=branch_list',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'charset' => 'utf8'
  ];
```

I only get this error when I am using Yii2 framework. I don't get it in other frameworks.

I even created a code to test my connection using this code and the connection is successful:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password= "";
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=branch_list", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I've tried reinstalling XAMPP, but nothing works.

Comment: Your error suggests that password is not used for the connection at all (it should be `YES`). I don't recall Yii having such feature to skip password when it's empty string but just in case change it to non-empty string and try again.

Comment: I also tried that, it's still not working. It just says SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

Try addin a new db user and use % for any host. See if you still are receiving the error. Attempt to connect to your DB via MySQL workbench, verify your credentials.

Did you deny remote access? Add permissions for user to the db table.